Why is my "Until" loops taking so long to complete in Azure Logic Apps?
I'm working on an Azure Logic App that includes a "Do Until" loop. The loop runs 4 iterations, and based on the action timings, each iteration takes about 1 minute to complete. However, I've noticed that the entire "Do Until" loop action is taking approximately 37 minutes to complete, which is far longer than the 4 minutes in total for all the iterations to complete.
Can anyone explain why this might be occurring? Theres nothing obvious in the run history or in the settings to explain this.
EDIT: Image of Do loop

EDIT 2: Stitched together runs of a Until loop and the timings after I've reduced the number of activities.

EDIT 3: I have switched to For Loops, while it has decreased the time, it still suffers from unexplained time differences between the total time taken for the actions within the loop and the loop to complete.

Do you mind sharing the activities and actions flow within the loop?

@LavizaFalakNaz I have updated the post with an image now

I remember you posted about this that your JS takes 10x more time with each loop. That can be a reason. Pull the JS outside of the loop and use the loop to only get the data and store it to a variable. once you have the data, you can use the JS to access it.

Please have a look at the post again, I have updated it to include a reduced Until loop without any JS. You can see from the image, the total activities equate to around to less than 4 minutes, yet the total time taken to complete the Until loop is 13 minutes.

Try checking start/end times of all individual actions in Log Analytics - table LogicAppWorkflowRuntime for Standard Logic Apps or AzureDiagnostics for Consumption Logic Apps.

I have checked in the logs and the same time discrepancies exist, it doesn't however show any additional information about why its taking that long
